# Extract month mean from time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, mean

I have some data in the following format:

```
    date     x     
    2001/06  9949 
    2001/07  8554  
    2001/08  6954 
    2001/09  7568 
    2001/10 11238  
    2001/11 11969 
    ... more rows
```

I want to extract the x mean for each month. I tried some code with aggregate, but
failed. Thanks for any help on doing this.

Comment: looks like you've already got it ...

Comment: No the data goes on: 2002/01...2012/01, 2012/02.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I simulate a data frame called `df` with more data:

```
df <- data.frame( 
      date = apply(expand.grid(2001:2012,1:12),1,paste,collapse="/"),
      x = rnorm(12^2,1000,1000),
      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Using the way your `date` vector is constructed you can obtain months by removing the firs four digits followed by a forward slash. Here I use this as indexing variable in `tapply` to compute the means:

```
with(df, tapply(x, gsub("\\d{4}/","",date), mean))
```

Comment: Notice that the result is a named vector in a different order. The names give the months.

Comment: Yes, i saw that - this reorder actually helps me!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry...just creat an month-sequence vector then used tapply.
It was very easy:

```
m.seq = rep(c(6:12, 1:5), length = nrow(data))
m.means = tapply(data$x, m.seq, mean)
```

But thanks for the comments anyway!